# How do I find out some information about a business in the early 1980s?

Tags: united-states, technology

I live outside the USA, and I need to find information about a certain "LAMO-LEM Laboratories", I have an address: Box 2382, La Jolla, CA 92038. But that's all. The web has not been kind to me wrt to this. Any ideas? A place I can find registration records, for instance?

Comment: Do you know it was a registered company? Looking at the info available, it produced a set of programs for the Sinclair ZX-81 computer. Given the platform, the odd mix of programs and the PO Box number, I'd be tempted to guess this was a hobbyist in his basement selling software as a sideline.

Comment: I would search newspaper archives of local California papers. Nexis would be a good start

Comment: Why do you want to find out? It could help us to assist you, though it's fine if it's private

Comment: @SteveBird: Correct! They did a bunch of programs for the ZX80 (earlier model than the 81). Interestingly, they produced "prints" for WWII topics, according to the link below. This also suggests that they were in the printing business, rather than the computer one. Ne-mo, nothing private, I'd just like to know who these people were. I enjoy computer archeaology :) http://www.ddg2014.altervista.org/materiale/PanzerLeader.pdf

Comment: IMHO this is on-topic here. However, you should be aware that there's also a SE site specifically for the [History of Science and Math](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/). I don't hang out there much, but given that this was a computer software company, such a question would seem right up their alley.

Comment: @T.E.D.: Sure! Should I migrate the question, then?

Comment: Wouldn’t Retro Computing be an even better place?